# How to configure ejabberd which is installed from Azure marketplace to Azure mysql as service?

Tags: ejabberd

I have created mysql instance in azure (Azure mysql service) and also I have created ejabberd from Azure market place (Ubuntu). I have done all the firewall configuration but unable to connect.

> error :2018-03-20 13:31:08.248 [error] <0.897.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:935
>   p1_mysql_conn: in it error 9002:
>   [35,50,56,48,48,48,83,83,76,32,99,111,110,110,101,99,116,105,111,
>   110,32,105,115,32,114,101,113,117,105,114,101,100,46,32,80,108,101,97,115,101,32
>   ,115,112,101,99,105,102,121,32,83,83,76,32,111,112,116,105,111,110,115,32,97,110
>   ,100,32,114,101,116,114,121,46,0] 2018-03-20 13:31:08.249 [error]
>   <0.378.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:935 p1_mysql_conn: po st_start error
>   login_failed 2018-03-20 13:31:08.249 [info]
>   <0.378.0>@ejabberd_sql:connecting:324 mysql conne ction failed:

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you comment this line in your MySql my.cnf file

```
#bind-address                   = 127.0.0.1
```

Allow your Ejabberd Ip to mysql

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'<<ejabberd private ip>>' IDENTIFIED BY '<<’mysql password’>>';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```